# How to edit the img src onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On a site with a lot of images I would like to add a mouseover event on each of them.

I could do it like this:

```
<img class="brand" 
     src="img/brands-grey/image1.svg" 
     onmouseover="this.src='img/brands/image1.svg';" 
     onmouseout="this.src='img/brands-grey/image1.svg';"/>
<img class="brand" 
     src="img/brands-grey/image2.svg" 
     onmouseover="this.src='img/brands/image2.svg';" 
     onmouseout="this.src='img/brands-grey/image2.svg';"/>`
```

But I rather would remove/insert "-grey" onmouseover/out from the src.
Could some one point out to me how to accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you just `remove/insert` **grey** from `url` when its gonna act same even though you do as you are doing now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put jQuery as a tag so here is a jQuery solution:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img.brand').mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('-grey', ''));
    }).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('brands', 'brands-grey'));
    });
});
```

The HTML will be much cleaner:

```
<img class="brand" src="img/brands-grey/image1.svg" />
<img class="brand" src="img/brands-grey/image2.svg" />
```

Instead of using 2 sets of images I would use an existent jQuery plugin like [jQuery.BlackAndWhite](https://gianlucaguarini.github.io/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
            <img class="brand" src="img/brands-grey/image1.svg" onmouseover="this.src='img/brands/image1.svg';" onmouseout="this.src='img/brands-grey/image1.svg';"/>
            <img class="brand" src="img/brands-grey/image2.svg" onmouseover="this.src='img/brands/image2.svg';" onmouseout="this.src='img/brands-grey/image2.svg';"/>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function(){
                jQuery('img.brand').hover(function(){
                    // this function will be called when the mouse in
                    var src= $(this).attr('src');
                    src.replace('brands-grey', 'brands')    ;
                    $(this).attr('src', src);
                },
                function (){
                    // mouse out handler
                    var src= $(this).attr('src');
                    src.replace('brands', 'brands-grey');
                    $(this).attr('src', src);
                }
                )
            })
            </script>
```

Please correct the the jquery path path. Here we used the jQuery hover method. And jsut implement the logic of add/remove gray part from the src as you asked.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use CSS pseudo class `:hover` and use any wrapper containing two images, this would have better behaviour in all cases:

HTML:

```
<span class="img-container">
    <img class="brand" src="img/brands-grey/image1.svg"/>
    <img class="brand-over" src="img/brands/image1.svg"/>
</span>
<span class="img-container">
    <img class="brand" src="img/brands-grey/image2.svg"/>
    <img class="brand-over" src="img/brands/image2.svg"/>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.brand-over {
    display: none;
}

.img-container:hover .brand-over {
    display: inline;
}

.img-container:hover .brand {
    display: none;
}
```

Now if `brands-grey` is just an grayed out image, you even don't need two different images, just use e.g `opacity: 0.4;` and on image over set opacity to 1.  [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6so1cefy/)

Or using CSS3 filter with transition: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6so1cefy/1/)